# convert PilImage to reportlab

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, qr-code, reportlab

I'm trying to convert in the air without save a temp file from image.pil.PilImage object ('qrcode.image.pil.PilImage') to Reportlab canvas.drawImage(pilimage, x, y, width=30, height=30)

I have this error:

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not PilImage

After that I tried use BytesIO to convert PilImage:

```
io_img = BytesIO(image)
```

I have this error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'PilImage'

```
io_img = StringIO(image)
```

> TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not PilImage

Everything what I found is solutions with saved file and reopen it!

Is there any way to convert PilImage object directly to reportLab, without saving file and open it !

Comment: What's a "PilImage" exactly?

Comment: 'qrcode.image.pil.PilImage', import qrcode, image = qrcode.make('str')

Comment: The ReportLab documentation says "You need the Python Imaging Library (PIL) to use images with the ReportLab package" and I have no idea what `qrcode.make('str')` returns—so that sounds like the cause of your problem.

Comment: Well, a `qrcode.image.pil.PilImage` isn't a the same type as an `Image` object created by the `PIL` (or `pillow`) module. So you must find some way to convert it. Can you read the individual pixels of the `qrcode.image.pil.PilImage` object? If you can do that, then you should be able convert it yourself, on-the-fly, in memory.

Comment: Thanks for your advice ! I found solution already !

Answer (score 2):

```
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader


pil_img = ImageReader(qrcodeclass.get_image())

canvas.drawImage(pil_img , x, y, width=30, height=30)
```